# Is there a way to create a matlab filter that will filter out dynamic tonal noise?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to make a filter in MATLAB/simulink that will filter out tonal noise that changes frequency. For example, a transformer is turned on and produces a 60Hz tone. I want the filter to recognize the tone and block the frequency that it is at.

The only method that I have come up with is a short time Fourier transform, recognize the peaks and locations, and then create a band stop filter at the specific frequency. I can do all of this with prerecorded audio, however, I have no idea how to set something like this up in simulink. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This question is probably better suited for the digital signal processing site.

Comment: Perhaps you should demonstrate how to do it with prerecorded audio and then rephrase your question as "how would I implement this algorithm in simulink"